# Swift method expects separator

Tags: swift, swift2

I created the following method:

```
class func getAEDbyReference(reference: String, completionHandler: (Result<AED, NSError>) -> Void {
    Alamofire.request(Router.GetAED(reference)).responseObject{(response: Response<AED, NSError>) in
        completionHandler(response.result)
}
```

The error I get is: `Expected ',' separator`

But why? i do not see the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a closing parenthesis after `Void`

```
class func getAEDbyReference(reference: String, completionHandler: (Result<AED, NSError>) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(Router.GetAED(reference)).responseObject{(response: Response<AED, NSError>) in
    completionHandler(response.result)
}
```